# How can I upgrade the eclipse version my STS is using?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I downloaded STS 3.2.0 with Juno 3.8 a month a go. Last week it updated my STS to 3.3.0 without automatically.

I've checked that Kepler 4.3 has come out and would like to upgrade my STS installation to use that. I don't want to just install the new package from the website as I loose all my configs and such when I do that.

Can anyone help?

Edit:
Or can anyone explain to how I can copy my settings etc. to a new installation of STS?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know STS. In a normal Eclipse installation, you can run Help -> Install New Software, add the Kepler update site using the "Available sites" link, close the dialog, run Help -> Check for Updates and Eclipse will update everything it can find, under the condition of not breaking dependencies.

Your settings are not lost, if you use your old workspace with your new installation (as the majority of settings has workspace scope and is stored within it). Therefore you can also  try the following: Install a newly downloaded version of Kepler besides your existing Eclipse. Then in the new installation run File -> Import -> Installation -> From existing to have it automatically copy plugins from the old installation to the new one. Afterwards install whatever is missing using the installation menus described at the top or using Help -> Marketplace.

Comment: Well I tried that and it was unable to update the actual eclipse stuff, even per hand as it had dependecy errors

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my STS from 3.3 to 3.5. The following method worked fine.

Open STS > Help > Check for updates > Choose the latest version and install (lists all plugins available for upgrade as well as STS).

Comment: Yes, but that works only on minor version upgrades but not between major versions

Comment: @deiga Thanks for  the precision. I upgraded from 3.8.4 to 3.9.0  following Aanu's method

Answer (score 0):

Open STS(Spring Tools Suite)-> Help -> Check for Updates -> it will automatically updates with latest version.

`Version: STS 3.8.0 requires a JDK 8 to run on top of.`

`STS 3.9.0 requires a JDK 8 to run on top of.`

`STS 3.9.4 requires a JDK8/9/10 to run on top of.`

`STS 3.9.6 requires a JDK8/9/10/11 to run on top of.`